# Wininet https not working on windows CE 4.2

Tags: c++, ssl, https, windows-ce, wininet

I have written a https POST test code on window Visual C++ 2008 using wininet API and it is working well. I can receive data from server and ignore certificate. However, there is nothing received from server if the same code will to be run on embedded platform of Window CE.net 4.2.
Anyone has success in using it on window CE, particularly 4.2? Is there any registry setting needed?.

i google and it seem 4.2 do support "Passport SSI 1.4 Authentication". Do that means SSL is supported?

http://www.ingenuityworking.com/knowledge/w/knowledgebase/windows-ce-net-4-2-pocket-pc-2002-and-windows-mobile-2003-software.aspx

Any suggestion ?
i do not intend to use curlib as that will increase the size of my final binary.
Thanks.

Comment: on which environment is your code running well?

Comment: It is tested and working well on PC environment, 32 and 64-bit, exact same win32 code.

Comment: Did you recomiple your code by creating a Smart Device Project in Visual Studio and using your specific WinCE SDK?